How to remove docker object not used for longer than one week?
docker system prune could be a great tool, but it seems to lack the most useful filter.
I would like to remove every docker object not used for longer than one week, but I can't find how to.
From the docs, docker system prune -af --filter until=168h

only remove containers, images, and networks created before given timestamp

but if yesterday I used an image created 2 years ago, I don't want to remove it.
How can I prune docker object but those recently used?

To the best of my knowledge, Docker doesn't maintain a "last used date" on resources, so there's no metadata on which to build such a filter.

# Remove containers that haven't been used for more than a week
docker container ls -aq --filter "until=168h" | grep -v $(docker container ls -aq --filter "label=keep=true") | xargs docker container rm -f

# Remove images that haven't been used for more than a week
docker image ls -aq --filter "until=168h" | grep -v $(docker image ls -aq --filter "label=keep=true") | xargs docker image rm -f

# Remove networks that haven't been used for more than a week
docker network ls -q --filter "until=168h" | grep -v $(docker network ls -q --filter "label=keep=true") | xargs docker network rm -f

docker object ls -aq --filter "until=168h" lists all Docker objects (images, containers, networks) that haven't been used for 7 days or more, returning only their IDs
grep -v $(docker object ls -aq --filter "label=keep=true") filters out the output of the 1st command from the 2nd. It removes object IDs listed in the output of the second command using grep -v.
xargs docker object rm -f takes the output from the previous commands and uses it as input for docker object rm
